# Invitation link for two users

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new in Node.js/Socket.io and in Back-End at all. While reading documentation I have started develop little project, but now I dont have enough knowledge to finish him.
So I'm trying to create simple game via those technologies (front-end in react.js) and now I need to create unique invitation for two players. How I can do this? If something is not clear, please ask.

*server.js*

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => { 

  socket.on('passDataToServer', (a) => { 
    console.log(a);
  });

  socket.on('create', (room) => {
    usersInRoom++;

    if (usersInRoom > 2) {
      console.log('room is full');
      return;  
    };

    socket.join(room);
    console.log(usersInRoom);
  });

});
```

*client.js*

```
function passDataToServer(data) {
  socket.emit('passDataToServer', data);
}

function creatingRoom() {
  socket.emit('create', 'room-1');
};

export { passDataToServer, creatingRoom }
```